# A Listview Item to be shown in a textbox

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

There is a `listview` which stores names from my `textbox` and when I select single name from a row in my `listview` I want that name to be shown back in my `textbox`. How can I do that ? I have a `person` list in my program that stores persons detail.

```
List<person> people = new List<person>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    if(!Directory.Exists(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\");
    if(!File.Exists(path+"\\AddressBook Data\\PeopleData.xml"))
        File.Create(path +"\\AddressBook Data\\PeopleData.xml");
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person p = new person();
    p.name = textBox1.Text;
    p.email = textBox2.Text;
    p.streetAddress = textBox3.Text;
    p.birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    p.addtionalNote = textBox4.Text;
    people.Add(p);
    listView1.Items.Add(p.name);

    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    textBox4.Text = "";
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other have said, you wire up the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

You can do something like this, which will repopulate all your fields when clicking on an item in the listview. We are using the `SelectedIndices` to get the current index of the selected item, and use that index to get the corresponding item in the `people` list.

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 1) // handle it some other way if you have multiselect.
        {
            int index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];

            Person p = people[index];

            if (p != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text = p.Name;
                textBox2.Text = p.Email;
                textBox3.Text = p.StreetAddress;
                textBox4.Text = p.AddtionalNote;
                dateTimePicker1.Value = p.Birthday;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Since the above method can be giving wrong result, e.g the list is sorted and the listview stays the same, the index from listview will give the wrong item from the people list.

So we are using the current selected name, and find the corresponding item in the `people` list.

```
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1) // handle it some other way if you have multiselect.
        {
            var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            Person p = people.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Text); 

            if (p != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text = p.Name;
                textBox2.Text = p.Email;
                textBox3.Text = p.StreetAddress;
                textBox4.Text = p.AddtionalNote;
                dateTimePicker1.Value = p.Birthday;
            } 
        }
```

Note: I took the liberty to change the property and class names to CamelCase.

Comment: Great, glad I could be of assistance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to listwievs  `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(listWiev1.Items[listWiev1.SelectedIndex]);
```

If you want to save modifys at the textbox, add a button and add this code to its `Click` event

```
listWiev1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: you mean selectedIndices nothing called seletedIndex its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectedItems` in `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void lstPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(lstPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0){ 
        txtName.Text = lstPeople.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a video i watched and i did as it said but not working                                                                http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=15&number=172 watch from 3.53 if you can

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index error coming

Comment: The _lstPeople.SelectedItems.Count > 0_ condition prevents that error.